# Is there a feature in Databricks that gives an estimate of the cost of a query before the cell is executed?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I've been working on Databricks for a while now and I have a question around predicting the cost of a query before the query is run. Is this a feature available in Databricks? I think it is available is Google's BigQuery

Comment: I'm guessing that there is not a feature for this?